# The footer Doesn't show at the end of div slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

The footer is missing after the end of division.

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section " id="section0"> content1 </div>
  <div class="section " id="section0"> content1 </div>
  <div class="section " id="section0"> content1 </div>
  <div class="section " id="section0"> content1 </div>
</div>
<footer> this is my footer </footer>
```

and this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {    
     $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        verticalCentered: false,
        resize : true,
        easing: 'easeInQuart',
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        scrollOverflow: false,
     });    
  });
</script>
```

I use the full page js scrolling is working smoothly but the footer is not showing.

Comment: Browser ? And which Version? It will not work in `IE<9` and for you information `id` must be unique in `valid HTML`

Comment: It's working when I copied your code inside fiddle.SO it may be some css issues

Comment: what will the full page plugin does?

Comment: this is the plugin i used to have the scrolling features
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#3rdPage

Comment: can you provide the CSS for the class section ??

Comment: sorry for the same ID it must be 0 1 2 3 sorry

Comment: i believe issue is with the attributes that you have given in full page plugin.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/ you will see that after 4 slide the scrolling return to normal. i was cloning this site.

Comment: provide the css atleast...

Comment: here the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rhyan_manlangit/7PwsS/701/

Comment: @RohanKumar it will work even in IE 8 and Opera 12.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check it. Here's [the example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html). Just scroll to the last section to see it working.

Answer (score 2):

This footer solution you tried is not supported by fullpage by default. I made a simple extension to the original fullpage.js, which supports this.

```
            if (v.anchorLink == 'footer')
            {
                footer_a = $('#section-footer').height();
                footer_h = $('#footer-text').height();
                var translate3d = 'translate3d(0px, -' + (v.dtop - footer_a + footer_h) + 'px, 0px)';
            }
            else
            {
                var translate3d = 'translate3d(0px, -' + v.dtop + 'px, 0px)';
            }
```

You can try it: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/reddy887/o4uywjrn/)

The footer height is calculated by the text in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle looks different to the code posted in your original question, however, the answer should still be applicable.

Change your css from:

```
#footer{
    bottom:0px;
}
```

To:

```
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GUTBA/

EDIT - The above will fix the footer to the bottom of the page for all sections. If the requirement is to show it after the last slide you will need to do one of the following:

**If the footer is a fixed height**
Change the css to:

```
#footer{
    bottom: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vU5hY/

This will shift the footer up from it's position after the slide by an amount equal to it's height.

**If the footer is not fixed height**
Change the css to:

```
#footer{
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.section {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Change the HTML to:

```
<div class="section" id="section3">
    <div class="sectionContent">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CKGQ5/

Move the footer into the last slide, set the container as position: relative; so that when we set the footer to position: absolute; it is positioned relative to it.

Comment: sorry for that but it almost the same.

anyway i don't want the footer to be fixed. i saw some site that can add footer after the scrolling of 4 slides.

Comment: So you only want the footer to appear after the final slide, not the ones preceding it?

Comment: Should be, can the footer be a set height?

Comment: Did either of the suggested solutions help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you use a new feature of fullpage.js 2.7.1. (auto-height sections)

Check out it [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections)

Here you have [an example online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html). Scroll to the last section.

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-fixed footer OUTSIDE the fullpage div. When I tried the above css code for a fixed-height footer, it resulted in an additional space below the footer equal to the height set in the 'bottom' attribute (in the above case, 20px).

However using the following code does not put in the extra space, and it can be used for a variable-height footer:

```
.footer {
    padding: 30px 0;
    bottom: 75px;
    margin-bottom: -75px;
    position: relative;
}
```